# How to use sql to get the first and last letter of every word in a string

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

E.g.
Today is a fine day

Results in
TYISAFEDY

I am using Oracle database.
Can it be done using regex?

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT value,
       UPPER(REGEXP_REPLACE(value, '(\w)(\w*(\w))?\W*', '\1\3')) AS firstandlast
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS
SELECT 'Today is a fine day' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | VALUE | FIRSTANDLAST |
> | --- | --- |
> | Today is a fine day | TYISAFEDY |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=14d87dfd2b53bd296da4d217eb50b5f5)*